# How can I resort (RowSort) after an insert in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, rowsorter

I would like to know: How can I reorder (re-sort) a `JTable` rows after I insert a row?

I use the next code:

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    Class returnValue;
    if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
      returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    } else {
      returnValue = Object.class;
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

This code works fine, and I can add new rows without problem, but I want after I insert a new row it re-sorts again using the first column ASC...

Comment: Try calling [`setSortsOnUpdates`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortsOnUpdates(boolean)) on the `TabkeRowSorter` and pass it `true`...Otherwise you could just call [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#sort())

Answer (score 1):

If you want real time updates, then you could try calling [`TableRowSorter#setSortsOnUpdates`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortsOnUpdates(boolean)) on the `TabkeRowSorter` and pass it `true`...

Otherwise, if you want to control when updates are sorted, you could just call [`TableRowSorter#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#sort())

If you want to modify the sort order programically, then take a look at [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) which has an example